# Unable to parse yaml file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I am trying to parse the below yaml file, tried using different yaml parsers but i'm unable to parse the yaml file.Is there way to parse this yaml file using any other python library.

```
policies:
  - name: test
    resource: ec2
    mode:
      type: periodic
      schedule: rate(1 day)
      role: arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/role_name
      tags:
        Name: ${tag_name}
        Project: ${tag_project}
    filters:
      - and:
        - type: value
          key: testname
          value: "${aws_account_id}"
        - type: value
          whitelist: %{ for acct_id in split (",", resource_list) }
            - "${acct_id}" %{ endfor }
```

python script:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

def print_table(filepath):
 file_name = Path(filepath)
 yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
 data = yaml.load(file_name)
 name = data['name']
 print(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_table('test.yaml')
```

Error:

```
ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "test.yaml", line 17, column 26
```

Comment: What does "unable to parse" mean? If you're getting an error, please edit your question to include the entire text of the traceback.

Comment: looks like your yaml file is invalid. Are there any other languages that work with this file?

Comment: Looks like your yaml got generated from a template, with the mistake of the `%{ endfor }` ending up in your yaml - it shouldn't.

Comment: I think this is a template for a yaml file that hasn't been run at all.

Comment: this is a custodian policy i have changed the values though for security issues.

Comment: @nadish, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `${{each in }}`.

```
policies:
  - name: test
    resource: ec2
    mode:
      type: periodic
      schedule: rate(1 day)
      role: arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/role_name
      tags:
        Name: ${tag_name}
        Project: ${tag_project}
    filters:
      - and:
        - type: value
          key: testname
          value: "${aws_account_id}"
        - type: value
          whitelist:
              ${{each acct_id in split (",", resource_list)}} - ${{acct_id}}
```